# sqlite3 in Python: How to average the values in a column based on a filter that works on 2 other columns?

Tags: python, sqlite

Below is a sample data I'm testing on:

```
---------------------------------------
|  id1  |  id2  |  cnt  |  avg_score  |
---------------------------------------
|   2   |   3   |   3   |     10      |
---------------------------------------
|   3   |   4   |   3   |     11      |
---------------------------------------
|   2   |   5   |   3   |     12      |
---------------------------------------
|   4   |   5   |   3   |     13      |
---------------------------------------
```

This is a data that details how many times 2 ingredients have been used together and how well the dish has turned out.

I am interested in calculating the average of the avg_score of each ingredient, no matter if they're in column id1 or id2.

The output should be as follows:

```
--------------------------
|  id  |  avg_avg_score  | 
--------------------------
|  2   |       11        | 
--------------------------
|  3   |       10.5      | 
--------------------------
|  4   |       12        | 
--------------------------
|  5   |       12.5      |  
--------------------------
```

Ingredient 3 appears in the first and second row, so the avg_avg_score is (10+11)/2.

I'm using sqlite3 in python.

Comment: See [Why is an average of an average usually incorrect?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/95909/why-is-an-average-of-an-average-usually-incorrect/95912)

Comment: Use a `UNION` to get all the ingredient IDs into a single column. Then you can easily use `AVG(avg_score) ... GROUP BY id`